# Save User using Realm Object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I am creating a project. I want if the `userID` already exist, it doesn't add the user. But somehow my code isn't working properly.

This is my Realm Model Object (User.swift):

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class User: Object {

    @objc dynamic var userID = Int()
    @objc dynamic var username = ""
    @objc dynamic var full_name = ""
    @objc dynamic var myBool = Bool()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "userID"
    }
}
```

And this is the button to add users:

```
@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
        let myUser = User()
        let JSON_userID = Int(arc4random_uniform(5)) // This is temporary. I am going to get code from JSON, but using random for testing purpose.

        if (myUser.userID != JSON_userID) {
            myUser.userID = JSON_userID
            myUser.username = "myUsername"
            myUser.full_name = "My Name"

            let realm = try! Realm()
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(myUser)
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Already exist")
        }
    }
```

Sometimes it runs the code, but most of the times it crashes with error:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`.

Comment: You have to query DB and test against all the users in it. Your if statement will be always true because you always test with newly created User.

Comment: What is the message of the exception?

Answer (score 3):

As you defined a primary key in your `User` object, [Realm can handle this automatically](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#objects-with-primary-keys) if you set the `update` parameter to `true` inside the `write` closure.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
   realm.add(myUser, update: true)
}
```

If the `update` parameter is not set or `false`, Realm will throw an exception when you try to add an object with an existing primary key.

This makes the `if / else` condition useless. It can be removed.

If you need to know if the user already exists, you can request the Realm with the primary key value:

```
realm.object(ofType: User.self, forPrimaryKey: JSON_userID)
```

The result will be `nil` if the user does not exist.

Comment: That actually works. But I have another function where it will update a boolean `@objc dynamic var myBool = Bool()` if the user already exist. How will that work with this code?

Comment: You can make a request on your Realm with the primary key like this: `realm.object(ofType: User.self, forPrimaryKey: userId) != nil`. This will return `true` if the user already exists.

Comment: So it should be like this then: http://oi68.tinypic.com/e7gvt1.jpg ? That still makes it crash.

Comment: EDIT: It also crashes even if I use `realm.add(myUser, update: true)`.

Comment: Well, if you want to do this, you need to use the value of the primary key (`JSON_userID`) and not the name of the property. But what I meant is that it's safer in term of architecture to remove the `if / else` completely and use `realm.add(myUser, update: true)`. Also, the `myBool` variable is not very clear to me but you should not store if the user already exist in the database because it is adding unnecessary complexity. Instead, make a request on the Realm to know if the object exists. I edited my answer with a link to the Realm doc.

Comment: Hm, I see.. If I have 2 booleans, and I only want to get object where one bool is true, and other one is false . Can I do something like: `var getData = realm.objects(User.self).filter("myBool = true, myBool2 = false")` or will that be totally wrong?